# Classloader in Applet: Can't access files

Tags: java, security, applet, classloader, sandbox

I have an application that uses reflection to instantiate code saved in some directory: I create a URLClassLoader that then loads the classes using the URLs provided; this works fine. I tried to port the application to an Applet. For loading text files and images, I changed the code from using relative paths to use `getResourceAsStream()` which works great. For the class loader, however, I still have an I/O exception (which I also used to get with the text files and images before I changed the code to use streams):

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /.../... read)
```

The classes to be loaded are contained in the jar file (as are all the other resources). Is there any way to load classes using something like `getResourceAsStream()` that does not invoke a security exception? Please note: I am talking about a class loader invoked from within the java code, not the class loader that loads the applet.

EDIT: More details on the file/folder structure:

My applet is in a package a, a.MyApplet, which makes use of a class a.aa.Loader which is meant to load classes stored in another folder b (hence not loaded when the applet is loaded). The folder b contains many directories, b.c_i, where c_i is a unique directory. In each of these directories are classes that belong to a package x.y.z, so the overall folder structure of b is b.c_i.x.y.z; z contains the file to be loaded. When I create the jar, the top-level looks like follows ([] indicates folder): [a],[b],[data],[images] where [a]={MyApplet,[aa],[aaa],etc.} and [b]={c_1,_c2,...} where c_i={[x]}, [x]={[y]}, [y]={[z]} and finally [z]={Class.class}. Hope the notation is not too weird.

Edit2: More details.

To clarify: the classes I want to load are classes by other people, all placed in a separate directory "DIR" (they are not part of the project nor do they form a project themselves). In fact, all these class names are identical, they are stored in unique directories within "DIR". I need to load one file at a time. In other words, I would like to treat the class files like any other resource.

NOTE: I tried a signed applet and it no longer throws a security exception but an IO one: it can not locate the file. I checked the directory structure and tried numerous variants, all with the same outcome (it works on my local machine). I am not sure if it is really an IO problem or whether it is still a security issue.

Comment: does the path in the FilePermission relate to one of the resources?

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, I just replaced the directory names with ... the structure of the jar file is as follows: [images] [data] [files to be loaded] [package]. The files to be loaded are in their own directory and the actual applet code is in [package]. Everything is in the jar file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: but the classes to be loaded are in a directory within the jar file. Why would it be different to the classes loaded as part of the applet?

Comment: @coderino Did you sign your applet?

Comment: @FrozenSpider No, it is currently not signed. I could sign it but would prefer not to (I think people are possibly put off by this). If that would be the only solution, however, I would of course do it.

Comment: @coderino Well, that's the easiest way and I don't know any way to load a class in runtime, that will bypass the `SecurityManager` (as this is not the action you want to be freely available to some random applet).

Comment: @coderino - actually, there shouldn't be any issue loading stuff from a jar which is already loaded in a classloader.  that's what i'm trying to understand.  how does the file path in the exception relate to the resources you are trying to load?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - loading something from an already loaded jar file is not a security bug.  if it was, applets would never be able to do anything.  where do you think all the applet classes come from?

Comment: @jtahlborn I agree, I think it should work. The exception shows the relative path to where the classes to be loaded are located. So, in the jar, the applet code is all part of package 'a' and is in a directory called 'a'. The classes to be loaded are in a directory called 'b' such that 'a' and 'b' reside on the same level. I had the same problem with the other files: when trying to load a text file using a path, it throws a security exception but asStream works. Hence I was wondering if classes could be loaded in the same way. I searched online for a long time but could not find an example.

Comment: @coderino - you don't load classes using asStream.  if the classes are already in the classpath, then you use `Class.forName()`.  i understand you don't want to give actual class details, but you need to be more specific if you want some help.  use fake dirs/packages if you want, but detail where stuff is and what exactly you are attempting to do.

Comment: @coderino Emm... the notation is really weird :) I couldn't read it so I hope you can provide it as a tree structure

Comment: @user592704 Yes, sorry about the weird notation. I can't upload images and could not figure out how to edit the text properly to indicate the directory structure. I added some more notes, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, keeping a project as a separate objects range that's a bad tone so...

- You can just pack all your project to a single jar file.
- In the case you keep your classes on server just because the whole
  project is too big you can compress it with pack200 util which is
  very helpful for Java Web Start fat client applets
- And I do recommend use jnlp applet launch type because it provides
  more options with its [DeployJava.js](http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js)

P.S.

And if you really insist to load resources with class loader do it in a applet standard manner I mean with an Anchor object

for example create structure like

- |- package images -
- |imageA.png
- |imageB.png
- |Anchor.class
- |SourceBound.class

---

SourceBound.java

```
public class SourceBound
{

  /**
    Conception only...
  **/
  public SourceBound(){}

  public ImageIcon getImageA()
  {
    ImageIcon icon;
    Image image;

    image=ImageIO.read(Anchor.class.getResourceAsStream("imageA.png"));
    icon=new ImageIcon(image);

    return icon;
  }
}
```

---

- |package test
- |Test.class

---

Test.java

```
public class Test
{

SourceBound sourceBound=new SourceBound();

Test()
{
  JButton button=new JButton();
  button.setIcon(sourceBound.getImageA());

}

}
```

Good luck