# Java - How to access an image packed in an applet jar

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have created an applet jar. That jar contains an images in the following folder

```
com\common\images\red.bmp
```

Now, I want to display this image on the Swing Applet.

```
private static final ImageIcon redIndicator = new ImageIcon("com\\common\\images\\red.bmp");
```

After that, I have attached the **redIndicator** to a `JPanel` but I am not able to see this image.

Any suggestions?

==================================EDITED=========================================

```
private static final ImageIcon marker = loadImage("com/common/images/scale.jpg");

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static ImageIcon loadImage(String imagePath) {

    BufferedInputStream imgStream = new BufferedInputStream(TpcHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(imagePath));
    int count = 0;

    if (imgStream != null) {

        byte buf[] = new byte[2400];

        try {
            count = imgStream.read(buf);
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (imgStream != null)
                try {
                    imgStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        if (count <= 0) {
            LOGGER.warning("Empty image file: " + imagePath);
            return null;
        }

        return new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(buf));
    } else {
        LOGGER.warning("Couldn't find image file: " + imagePath);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

at line `count = imgStream.read(buf);`

Comment: Parts of a path in a Jar are separated by '/', not '\' (on every OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `YourPanel.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/common/images/red.bmp")`, read the stream to a `byte[]` and construct the `ImageIcon` based on that. (and don't use bmps - prefer png or jpeg)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (if called from a class loaded from that same jar):

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/common/images/red.bmp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Applets and Images that is a frequently asked questions so, as for Java applets and images, I recommend you read [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484321/classloader-in-applet-cant-access-files/7493584#7493584) hope it helps a bit :)

Good luck